# How to do "append if exists" in Python?

Tags: python, append

I am trying to do the following operation.

```
    rating = []

    for i in result['search_results']:

        rating.append(float(i['rating']) if i['rating'] exists else 'NaN')
```

The API call sometimes does not return this value. How can I do an append if exists logic in Python?

Comment: `float(i['rating']) if 'rating' in i else 'NaN'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `get` method in a dictionary to retrieve a value if it exists and return a default value otherwise.

```python
rating = []
for i in result['search_results']:
    rating.append(float(i.get('rating', math.nan)))
```

Comment: Nice solution, it saves a lot of code.